# R - transpose dataframe from existing data frame and convert it to time-series

Tags: r, time-series, data-transformation

I'm beginning with R and I would like to transpose the following data frame

[image: initial dataframe]

into another dataframe with the column names being the company names and the vector values for each column (company names) being the return. As there is one return observation for each company on every date mentioned in the column date, I would like to convert the new dataframe into a time-series.

Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use spread from [tidyr](https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/spread.html). E.g. for price:

```
df %>% spread(`company name`, price)
```

Comment: Thank you very much